# Node.js bracket showing as first

Tags: node.js

im wondering why the bracket that is last in code shows as first

example:

```
console.log("(" + host + ":" + port + ")")
```

In console:
**)217.27.149.190:4153**

Comment: This code `var host = '1.2.3.4'; var port= 3000; console.log("(" + host + ":" + port + ")")` produces the expected `(1.2.3.4:3000)` Are you sure you do not have another console.log in your code which could print this? What you claim simply can't be true.

Comment: Try to simply `console.log(host)` separately and see if it has the `)` prefix. The code in the question `console.log("(" + host + ":" + port + ")")` will not generate an output that starts with `)`.